# Need to trim string based on value

Tags: input, trim

```
var a = 123456789
var b = 6
```

based on 'b' I need to trim 'a'. example if 'a' having 8 digits I need to trim 'a' upto 6 digits(123456). if b is 8 I need to trim upto 8 digits. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest way to do what you want is to:

1. Convert `a` to a string.
2. Take the left-most digits up to a maximum of `b`.

This is likely easier than trying to do what you ask arithmetically.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're in javascript?

```
var a = "123456789";
var b = 6;
var n = a.substr(0,b);
```